# How to insert an array inside a callback function

Tags: php, json, rest

I have an array generated from my Entity from the following code:

```
$albums = $this->objectRepository->findAll();

$collection = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($albums);        
$array = $collection->map(function($a){
    $a->songs = $a->songs->map(function($p){
        return $p->toArray();
    })->toArray();
    return $a->toArray();
})->toArray();
```

Like you see, there is a songs key into my array, which is a oneToMany association from a list of songs 
in an album represented by the Song Entity. this give me an array of songs in an array of albums.

Here is my (simplified) callback for a json representation:

```
$fractal = new \League\Fractal\Manager();
$resource = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($albums, function(Album $album) {

    return [
        'id'      => (int) $album->id,
        'title'   => $album->title,
        'artist'    => $album->artist,
        '_embedded' => [
            '_links' => [ $album->songs->songTitle ], //return null             
        ],              
    ];
});     
$result = $fractal->createData($resource)->toArray();          
return $result;
```

But how to do for inserting my list of songs into my callback?

Here is a for loop that give a list of songs outside the callback and null inside

```
$songs = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($array[0]['songs']); $i++)       
$songs[$i]['href'] = $array[0]['songs'][$i]['songTitle'];       
var_dump($songs);die;
```

So My question is How to insert an array inside a callback function?

Comment: Have you already tried to use `use`? e.g. `Collection($albums, function(Album $album) use ($varToPassToFunction) {`?

Comment: No, you would pass the for loop in this variable?

Comment: You have to pass the variable to it that you want to use inside your anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry for delay in my reply.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry for delay in my reply.  Finally I put my loop for inside the callback like this  `for($i=0; $i<count($array['songs']); $i++) $songs[$i]['href'] = '/album/' . $array['id'] . '/' . $array['songs'][$i]['songTitle'];` and in my array `'rel' => $songs`